# Overwriting content from one table to existing table

Tags: mysql, copying

I have two different tables with two colums that have the same name, datatype and size.

**My issue:**

When I try to copy the content from one column to the other,

```
update Table1
set Column4 = (select Column1 from Table2);
```

I get an error. (subquery returns more than one row)

**My question:**

Is there a way for me to copy the content from Table2 to Table1 in a similar fashion as the code shows above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Insert ... Select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
Insert INTO Table1 (Column4)
SELECT Column1 FROM Table2
```

Comment: I get the error message: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'. 
Table1 contains a key and a couple more columns than Table2. Which could be related to the issue, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @user5553 you will need to extend my query as per your actual table structure, to include rest of the columns